# Regenerated folder showing as "modified" by Git

Tags: git

I have a script that I use to build releases. It performs numerous validation checks; including making sure that the code is unmodified; relative to the repository.

As part of this process, a folder under Git is deleted and then recreated. The problem is that somehow `git diff-index` is reporting it as modified; however, the changes are not visible using `git diff`.

I created a minimally reproducible example:

**File Structure:**

```
    - script.sh (see below)
    - my_dir
      - 1.txt 
      - 2.txt 
      - 3.txt 
      - 4.txt
```

Files 1-4.txt are empty text files.

**script.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh                                       
                                                
echo "Hello"

# Replace the original my_dir folder with a clone.                                              
cp -r my_dir my_dir2                            
rm -rf my_dir                                   
mv my_dir2 my_dir                               
                                                
if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- ; then      
        echo "ERROR"                            
        git diff HEAD --                        
        git diff                                
        git status --short                      
        exit 1                                  
fi
```

When running the script, it fails; reporting the following:

```
Hello
ERROR
```

Notice the absence of any `diff` output.

**Question:** This is very counterintuitive to me. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried `git diff-tre`, `git diff-files`? It may be that for optimization purposes it only compares timestamps if you ask it to report "are there *any* changes".

Comment: Amazing. Yes, it seems that changing my condition to `if ! git diff-files --quiet ; then` seems to do the trick. Thanks for your help; although I'm still extremely surprised by all this!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: If you write it up as an answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: I'm curious what `git diff-index` shows, if you were to replace the `git diff HEAD` with `git diff-index HEAD` inside the test.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not write that up as an answer. I do not know conclusively why the diff-index command tells you that there is a difference, so I'll simply hold off on this. If anyone has any more information they can of course post their own answer instead, but I generally don't like to post guesses which are not conclusively verified as answer.

Comment: This does seem very odd. A quick look through the diff-index code shows a lot of shortcuts it will take when doing this kind of status-only diff, but it's not clear to me whether any of those is causing the issue.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: I ended up using `git diff --exit-code HEAD --` and now it works as expected. I still don't understand _why_ this works, as opposed to `git diff-index`, but at least I have an operational workaround.

Answer (score 1):

When you say absence of diff output do you mean completely blank or there are some lines with no visible diff.

May be the diff is of whitespaces that why they are not visible.

Comment: There are no lines reported as modified. I think whitespace differences would be report but hard to see. Here, the lines themselves are not reported at all.

Comment: Since you used the operating system command to copy the files wholesale there shouldn't be **any** differences to the file contents. The file *metadata*, however, will differ.